# How can I create a regular expression that requires 4 characters and no spaces?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

I am trying to make the user input exactly 4 characters with no spaces... here's what I have:

```
.[^\s]{4}
```

but everything I enter says that it didn't match the regex...

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: when you say characters, do you mean only alpha characters and not numeric?  Can you give an example of what should match and what shouldn't b/c the regex I gave you should match a four character long string, but it will match any for characters as long as they are not spaces.  If you something that will match only alpha chars you would do  /^[^\s\d]{4}$/

Comment: I'm confused, b/c the answer you accepted is the same answer as I provided you in comments which you stated did not work. ?  The only thing different is the /'s on the beginning and end that are considered generic indicators of a regular expression.

Comment: Maybe he is in an environment that doesn't want the /'s to delimit the regular expression, and didn't know to take them out.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Why is there an extra `.` in front?  That will match a separate character before your "four non-spaces" get counted.

You probably also want to bind it to the beginning and end of the string, so:

```
^[^\s]{4}$
```

Comment: @Kelsey: [^\s] is the same as [\S]

Comment: @Kelsey:  The ^ at the beginning of the string means it only matches the beginning of the string, and the $ at the end means it only matches the end of the string.

Comment: Ah but one takes more typing to produce the same results:) i++; or i = i + 1; :P

Comment: @yodaj007 I know taht the ^ and $ do, see my answer below where I explained it all in detail.  I just thought the use of two ^ was not needed.

Comment: The two ^ have completely different meanings.  The one at the beginning binds to the beginning of the string, as in your example; the one inside the character class negates that class.  As R. Bemrose points out above, [^\s] is the same as [\S].  I used the former only because that's what was in Matt's original code.

Answer (score 11):

Your making it more complicated than it needs to be and using `\S`, not `\s` so you don't match spaces. I think this should work for you:

```
^[\S]{4}$
```

**Definition of solution:**

^ - begins with

[/S] - capital 'S' means no white space

{4} - match 4 times

$ - end of string

Answer (score 1):

```
\S{4}
```

will match 4 non-whitespace characters. If you are using c# regex, I highly recommend [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm).

Comment: Problem is because you have excluded the beginning and ending bits, it will also match text that is greater than 4 characters.  He wants exactly 4 characters.

Answer (score 1):

In Java:

```
[^\s]{4,4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like /^[^\s]{4}$/

Answer (score 0):

try out [txt2re.com](http://txt2re.com)  works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful if someone is looking for 4 characters only, no numbers,spaces or special characters

```
var regexp = /^([a-zA-Z]){4}$/;
console.log(regexp);
var isValid = regexp.test('abcd');
console.log("Valid: " + isValid);
```